# Codeigniter handling lang files?

Tags: codeigniter, exception, lang

I know how to use CI lang helper and lang class, but my question is it possible to 
use lang files from other directory than SYSTEM, maybe i can make a new folder in root of app and call language files from there?

And other thing, is is good handling of lang files that CI done?

I want to add somthing that user can uplaod lang files, but structure need to be checked, here

is an example

```
$lang["msg_first_name"] = "First Name";
```

This is proper lang line, but what if some upload file that looks like this?

```
$lang["msg_first_name"] = "First Name i "Michael" and i like chocolate";
```

You see there is two

> "

Does that will create error in lang file, or CI handle that, i or must made a custom class
that will handle that error?

Answer (score 0):

Why the your language in the stystem folder it should be inside the `application/language` folder. And its not really a good idea to upload the language by user. Its a big `SECURITY HOLE` because any one can upload any script and that will be executed by your code. You never should allow to upload any executable code in your system.

And if you upload a broken file it will cause the php error. So when there is a php error codeigniter cannot do anything about this. Just simply think you are including a php file as normally you would do for any php. So CI doing the same then reading some variable(`$lang`) and assigning to the a class nothing else.

And yes you can use your define folder to load the language you can do this in few way

```
        $this->load->add_package_path('YOUR_PATH');
        //so your language will be YOUR_PATH/language/YOUR_LANG_FOLDER(english default)
         $this->load->language('language_file'); //user

       OR

        $this->lang->load('YOUR_LANG_FILE','LANG',FALSE,TRUE,'YOUR_PATH') ;

        //look the function description 
        /**
 * Load a language file
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   mixed   the name of the language file to be loaded. Can be an array
 * @param   string  the language (english, etc.)
 * @param   bool    return loaded array of translations
 * @param   bool    add suffix to $langfile
 * @param   string  alternative path to look for language file
 * @return  mixed
 */  

    OR extend the CI_Lang and modify the load function they way you want, to do this you have to create a file `application/core/MY_Lang.php` 

    class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang {

          //OVERWRITE THE FUNCTION 
          function load($langfile = '', $idiom = '', $return = FALSE, $add_suffix = TRUE, $alt_path = ''){

       //MODIFY THE THE CODE FOMR CI_Lang AND SET THE INCLUDE PATH AS YOU WANT
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but no end user will upload file, only sys admin, about hole it is not a problem, it is possible to put lang in other folder, or i can direct upload to system folder, does CI allow to upload to system folder?

Comment: I did modify my answer, when you mean system folder do you mean application folder. you should not write your code inside the system folder, system folder should have all CI code, you should extend the classes in your application as you need. And yes you can upload anywhere you want its depend on you and the way you set your upload path

Answer (score 0):

You may write different language files and load them whenever you want. Read the following link: http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-language-support-in-codeigniter/

The folder you put your files is application/language/[LANG], and then you just call them in your controller, no need to any further modification. It's important note that the files MUST finish with "_lang.php"

About uploading the file, just deploy your language file (must have the same name in the different languages folders) into the folder and just go. What I've done with similar multilanguages files is building a controller which I use to import the languages lines from a CSV files and write the different lines into the language files:

```
Code    | Message
name    | Su nombre
surname | Su apellido
```

With that, you write the whole language file from there, checking for weird symbols. You may even have several columns with different languages, and keep the coherence with it because you overwrite the file every time you launch the importer_language:

```
Code    | MsgSpanish     | MsgEnglish
name    | Su nombre      | Your Name
surname | Su apellido    | Your Surname
```

Comment: Nice i was thinking about that, do you have that ind of controller?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't post it, but the idea is to use fgetcsv function to get line by line of code from the CSV, check and filter every input, open different language files, with the key 0 as code inside of the $route and the phrase depending on the language key, and then write every line into the different files. For reading the whole CSV you may check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php. It's a pretty cool problem manage all the files at the same time, I enjoyed it and I hope you'll do it too XD